# Xorg.conf options not staying

Tags: x11, xorg, udev, touchpad, xinput

I am trying to enable tap to click by default on my trackpad. The device name is "bcm5974". `xinput --set-prop "bcm5974" "libinput Tapping Enabled" "1"` works a charm, but properties changed like this don't stick after a restart.

Following other answers on here, I modified `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`. First I ran `xinput list`, where my device came up as a pointer, so the relevant section of `40-libinput.conf` became:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
```

This did not work, so I had a look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, which showed that the device was actually being recognised as a touchpad. I changed `40-libinput.conf` to add `Option "Tapping" "on"` to the touchpad InputClass instead.

Tap to click was still not enabled after a restart, but the `Xorg.0.log` did show the option being set, before the device is removed then apparently readded without reading `40-libinput.conf`.

```
[    73.350] (II) config/udev: Adding input device bcm5974 (/dev/input/event6)
[    73.350] (**) bcm5974: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    73.350] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'bcm5974'
[    73.350] (**) bcm5974: always reports core events
[    73.350] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    73.350] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    73.357] (II) event6  - bcm5974: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    73.358] (II) event6  - bcm5974: device is a touchpad
[    73.358] (II) event6  - bcm5974: device removed
[    73.394] (**) Option "Tapping" "on"
[    73.394] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.2/input/input6/event6"
[    73.394] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "bcm5974" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[    73.395] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    73.395] (**) bcm5974: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    73.395] (**) bcm5974: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    73.395] (**) bcm5974: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    73.402] (II) event6  - bcm5974: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    73.403] (II) event6  - bcm5974: device is a touchpad
[    73.404] (II) config/udev: Adding input device bcm5974 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    73.404] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    73.404] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

I'm beyond my level of knowledge here. Is udev applying its own config to my device, and if so, where is the config file located and how do I modify it? Or am I missing something else?

I'm running Lubuntu 20.04.5 on a late 2008 Macbook, and the trackpad is the laptop's original built-in one. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: What DE are you using ? Would some DE system-settings override whatever xorg.conf setting ?

Comment: I think that's it and I've been making this all more difficult than I needed to. I'm on LXQt. Under 'Keyboard and Mouse' in lxqt-config there was an option under touchpads for 'Single click to activate items'. I'd always assumed this meant click once to open files/folders/etc. Turns out it actually activates tapping. A bit misleading to my mind, but there you go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.