# I need to activate tap to click on a Lenovo E525

Tags: kubuntu

I want to activate tap to click on my Lenovo e525 trackpad using libinput.
I have list-devices saying that its not activated.
I'm on Kubuntu 22.04.

How do I do this?

Comment: Could this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732153/xorg-conf-options-not-staying#comment1389403_732153 (and comments) help you finding your way (between xorg.conf settings / xinput command / DE settings) ?

Comment: BTW, Kubuntu means that your DE is KDE-Plasma. Right ? => System-settings > Input Devices > Touchpad

Comment: Yes - its KDE-Plasma

Comment: The Plasma UI touchpad tap section is disabled - this is soooo frustrating.

Comment: Then you might have a problem with the driver. Check into your bootlogs for infos regarding this particular device enumeration. Should in final be attached to some HID driver.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Xorg, a simple way would be to create a new file under  `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` :

`sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf`

and add a basic configuration for the trackpad, like:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "libinput"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Option "Tapping" "on"
  Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
  Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
EndSection
```

Worth checking that there is not already a file there for the touchpad, in that case simply add `Option "Tapping" "on"` to it.

The config should kick in after rebooting.

I'm sure however that there is a graphical way in KDE. If you go in Settings and search "Tap" you'll probably find it the correct switch.

Comment: There is a touchpad UI option but the "tap to click" option is disabled. Does that mean it cant be set?